# Importing .less from Meteor into Semantic UI

Tags: meteor, less, semantic-ui

I'd like to define my vars in Meteor's `/client/styles/vars.less` and import it into Semantic's `site.variables.import.less` but can't seem to figure out how.

Using `@import "../../../../styles/vars.less"` didn't seem to work, neither did `@import "{}/client/styles/vars.less"`

Answer (score 0):

turns out it *was* working, but the automatic reloading wasn't picking it up. doing `meteor reset` and `meteor` got it working!